# A href click and onClick at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using an onClick event to push a data layer to Google Tag manager but I also want to send the user to a page using the `a href`. Because of this I don't think my event is being recorded in Google Analytics because the page has been redirected before the event has been recorded.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.gtm-click-evt').click(function(){
        var dataAmount = $(this).data('value').replace("$", ""); //Remove dollar sign
        var value = parseInt(dataAmount); //convert to int
        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'clickEvent',
            'category': $(this).data('category'),
            'action': $(this).data('action'),
            'label': $(this).data('label'),
            'value': value
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="/want-to-also-redirect-to-a-page"
   class="gtm-click-evt gtm-colo btn btn-primary bg-green"
   data-category="productClick"
   data-action="colocationClick"
   data-label="label"
   data-value="99">
   Buy Now
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop the default action (event.preventDefault();) run your essential code and then wait for a second and redirect.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.gtm-click-evt').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var dataAmount = $(this).data('value').replace("$", ""); //Remove dollar sign
    var value = parseInt(dataAmount); //convert to int
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'clickEvent',
        'category': $(this).data('category'),
        'action': $(this).data('action'),
        'label': $(this).data('label'),
        'value': value
    });
     url=$(this).attr('href');
    setTimeout(function(){location.href = url}, 1000);
});
});
```

Comment: The href tag is still getting fired first because I changed the 1000 to 10000 and the page just goes straight off without waiting therefore not hitting the prevent.default

Comment: Ok, thanks this works...In order to make it work though I updated the setTimeout into a function setTimeout(function(){location.href = url}, 1000);

Answer (score 1):

You can just redirect the user to the page in the function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.gtm-click-evt').click(function(){
    var dataAmount = $(this).data('value').replace("$", ""); //Remove dollar sign
    var value = parseInt(dataAmount); //convert to int
    dataLayer.push({
        'event': 'clickEvent',
        'category': $(this).data('category'),
        'action': $(this).data('action'),
        'label': $(this).data('label'),
        'value': value
    });
    window.location = "/want-to-also-redirect-to-a-page";
  });
});
```

And then the link change:

```
<a class="gtm-click-evt gtm-colo btn btn-primary bg-green"
    data-category="productClick"
    data-action="colocationClick"
    data-label="label"
    data-value="99">
    Buy Now
</a>
```

Comment: The location is going to change depending on the button so I don't want to code this into the method. I just want to separate the GTM data layer event with the site navigation and not include this in the the function

Comment: @ottz0 Since you are using element selection to find these links, you could store the destination in a `data` value as well, and dynamically send the user there in the function. E.g., `data-dest="/want-to-also-redirect-to-a-page"` and  `window.location = $(this).data('dest')`.

Comment: Follow up to my own comment, this method can still stop things before the event is fired. The redirect should use the `eventCallback` function to operate, but you will also need to account for cases where GTM is blocked by an ad or tracking blocker.